# Strange Mongo DB writelock values in logfile

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting some strange writelock values in my Mongo DB logfile:

```
Wed Mar 19 10:03:47.007 [snapshotthread] cpu: elapsed:4010  writelock: 0%
Wed Mar 19 10:03:51.007 [snapshotthread] cpu: elapsed:4000  writelock: 0%
Wed Mar 19 10:03:55.012 [snapshotthread] cpu: elapsed:4005  writelock: 0%
Wed Mar 19 10:03:59.028 [snapshotthread] cpu: elapsed:4015  writelock: 385%
Wed Mar 19 10:04:03.042 [snapshotthread] cpu: elapsed:4014  writelock: -2147483648%
Wed Mar 19 10:04:07.045 [snapshotthread] cpu: elapsed:4003  writelock: 0%
```

Is this 'normal' or should I be worried?

Comment: you asked this on mongodb-users group - it's a more appropriate question for that forum. But short answer - there is nothing wrong with your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is 'normal MongoDB behaviour'...